# Asp.net MVC employ a controller's Disposable Property in other controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have a `Disposable` property in a controller is needed in other controllers too. For example, suppose the following property in a controller:

```
public ClassName<Template> Name { get; set; }
```

Which will be instantiated in the same controller's constructor like this:

```
public SomeController()
            : this(new ClassName<Template>())
{
}

public SomeController(ClassName<Template> name)
{
    Name = name;
}
```

**Can I use the property by instantiating the container controller in other controllers?**

Comment: Just a question: if it's a singleton then there is no need for a property and if it's not...how will you create an instance of the other controller?

Comment: Why not make it an abstract property on a base class that inherits from `Controller`

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi do you mean you need **same property** in multiple controllers or you want to reuse **same instance**?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti From your questions/suggestions, I learned some tips and updated the question to be more constructive. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is: *can I create an instance of the controller and use it in another one*, the answer is yes, controllers are just classes which you can instantiate and use. Just like any other.

The thing that concerns me though, is that it seems you are using a property that should be a proper singleton as something that isn't, by re-instantiating another class that seems slightly related. If you can, move the property to an other class. [Make it singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx), and use it accordingly.

Comment: Bravo! That's exactly what I mean and need. Just I didn't know how to describe my question. regards.